# AJAX Send array as response from Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, laravel, post

I am trying to send from Laravel a response to an AJAX post request.

```
public function infoRoute(Request $request)
    {
        // Get info
        $ship_id = $request->ship_id;
        $startDate = $request->datepicker_start;
        $endDate = $request->datepicker_end;

        // Get all the locations between those dates
        $routeArray = $this->measurementRepository->getCoordinates($ship_id, $startDate, $endDate);

        $ship = $this->shipRepository->getShipForId($ship_id);
        $info = $this->createRouteArrayForShip($ship, $routeArray);

        if($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(json_encode($info));
        }
    }

    protected function createRouteArrayForShip($ship, $routeArray)
    {
        $info['type'] = "showRoute";

        $index = 0;

        foreach($routeArray as $coordinates)
        {
            $info['info']['route']['loc'. $index] = $coordinates;
            $index++;
        }

        $info['info']['shipInfo'] = $ship;

        //dd($info);
        return $info;
    }
```

When I receive the information and process it with jQuery, everything shows except from the route, that is empty.

Thank you,

Comment: if you use your browser developer tools.. what data do you see coming back in the response?

Comment: You have a multidimensional array there..

Comment: Try to return it as a JSON

Comment: At least you don't need `response()->json(json_encode($info));`, use `response()->json($info);`

Comment: @Dale What I get back is an Object, containing an Object "info" and a string "type". Inside "info" I only get the object shipInfo. But there is no sign of route

Comment: So if you `print_r($routeArray)` before the `foreach($routeArray...)` there's data? What is `print_r($index)` after the `foreach`? Also `print_r($info)`?

Answer (score 3):

The `response()->json()` method converts the given array into JSON using the `json_encode()` PHP function behind the scene.
Therefor you should remove your `json_encode()` from inside the `response()->json()` call.

Basically it should look like this

```
return response()->json($info);
```

Comment: Thank you! I have done that but it still isn't working. I think it has something to do with the fact that `$info` does not contain the coordinates from the route. It is sent empty. If I do `dd($info)` before returning the response, the route is empty. But when I call the function createRouteArrayForShip it actually saves the records in the array